# eprocessing network ios sdk integration

Tags: ios

As of my requirement, I need to integrate eprocessing network payment gateway to my application for credit card payment transactions. I didn't find any SDK or sample codes to implement. Anyone integrated eprocessing network, Please help me here.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per discussion with eProcessing Network Support team, Sales representative will provide the access for SDK and related documentation once we registered with them.

Answer (score 1):

[Eprocessing Network](http://www.eprocessingnetwork.com) allows developers to use their existing mobile framework (including an integrated, encrypted audio jack card reader) from which to implement their own payment application. We provide developers the business logic, and the presentation layer is left to their imagination.

Here is the documentation for Mobile SDK (PDF Format):

iOS :- http://www.eprocessingnetwork.com/docs/SDK/iOS_SDK_Developers_Guide_v2.1.pdf
Android :- http://www.eprocessingnetwork.com/docs/SDK/Android_SDK_Developers_Guide_v2.1.pdf

SOME CODE FOR REFERENCE :-

```
icharge.Gateway = IchargeGateways.gwEprocessing;

//This is your eProcessingNetwork account number.
//For testing you may use the value 05971
icharge.MerchantLogin = "05971";

//MerchantPassword is not used
icharge.MerchantPassword = "";

icharge.Card.CVVData = "123";
icharge.Card.ExpMonth = 2;
icharge.Card.ExpYear = 11;
icharge.Card.Number = "05971";
icharge.Customer.Address = "1234 Nowhere Ln";
icharge.Customer.City = "Beverly Hills";
icharge.Customer.Country = "US";
icharge.Customer.Email = "nobody@server.com";
icharge.Customer.FirstName = "John";
icharge.Customer.Id = "CUSTOMER1";
icharge.Customer.LastName = "Smith";
icharge.Customer.Phone = "555-555-5555";
icharge.Customer.State = "CA";
icharge.Customer.Zip = "90210";
icharge.InvoiceNumber = "1234";
icharge.TransactionAmount = "1.00";
icharge.TransactionDesc = "Test Transaction";
icharge.Sale();
```

I hope this helps you. Any question you can ask in comments !!!

Comment: i would like to more about the payment do you know any application or any video. that do the payment

Comment: What exactly you want ? isn't above info enough. Please clear what you looking for.

Comment: ahhhh...i am working for the mall application. when the user select the items that they want to buy. so when user reaches to the payment counter it will directly pay with mobile. i am doing that type of research

Comment: You ask about Eprocessing network. So I exlained about that. There are so many ways of payment. One you can read http://www.raywenderlich.com/30092/how-to-accept-credit-cards-in-your-ios-apps-using-stripe.

Comment: thanks for your response @ArpitKumarKulshrestha, In that document i didn't find the SDK, Please provide the ePN_SDK link. that would helps

Comment: can anybody please share the ePN_SDK or containing sample code. I am in urgent need of it.

Comment: Hello @ArpitKumarKulshrestha can you please provide the ePN_SDK(Framework) contained link or sample project.

Comment: @Vinodhraju you can find sample code here :- http://www.nsoftware.com/kb/xml/01191001.rst

Comment: @ArpitKumarKulshrestha i didn't find the ePN_SDK in the above link, Please provide the SDK which is required to initialise the implementation.

Comment: @Vinodhraju I too didn't find it. But you said in your answer that you got this after talking with support team

Comment: No, even they sent this link http://www.eprocessingnetwork.com/docs/SDK/iOS_SDK_Developers_Guide_v2.1.pdf. Not exactly the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

eProcessing Network provides plenty of SDK support on their site for registered developers. Whether you are building an app for a phone, an e-commerce plugin such as WooCommerce, or even a physical device -- there is PLENTY of support[enter link description here][1] available from them directly.

Comment: "[enter link description here][1]" you should edit your post, the link is missing.